# Obj-C Add project dependency but main Project can not find header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have added one project dependency inside of my project. After that, I have also add to header search path, target dependencies and linked frameworks and libraries also.

**Error:**

[image]

[image]

**Header Search Path:**

[image]

**Library:**

[image]

**Target Dependency:**

[image]

What did i miss to make it run? Please give me an advice. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also add the **Library Search Path**. Add the path where your .a file is located in your file system.

[image]

Please also make sure that your .a file appears in the **Link Binary With Libraries** section in Build Phases and the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** section in General.

**Link Binary With Libraries**
[image]

**Linked Frameworks and Libraries**
[image]